# How to build a url of a GRAVATAR image from a given email

Tags: php, gravatar

There is a simple way with **php**, a simple script or URL manipulation to build a URL for the **gravatar** image corresponding to an email?

`Ex. http://gravatar.com/avatars/avatar.php?email=myemail@myserver.com` and this return a jpeg or png image.

If there is no simple way like the example, what is the easiest way you know to resolve a url of the gravatar corresponding to an email?. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find a sample script with PHP code on their implementation site: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/php

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
$userMail = whatever_to_get_the_email;

$imageWidth = '150'; //The image size

$imgUrl = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($userMail).'?size='.$imageWidth;
```

(Fixed the $imgUrl)

Comment: There's an error in the url, before md5 of user email there should be no `.`

Answer (score 6):

The root script is at http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/
The next part of the URL is the hexadecimal [MD5 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5) of the requested user's lowercased email address with all whitespace trimmed. You may add the proper file extension, but it's optional.

The complete API is here http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/

Answer (score 1):

Though @dipi-evil's solution works fine, I wasn't getting larger image with it. Here's how I got it working properly.

```
$userMail = 'johndoe@example';

$imageWidth = '600'; //The image size

$imgUrl = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($userMail).'?size='.$imageWidth;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just see this simple function of Gravatar which can:

1. Check if the email has any gravatar or not.
2. Return the gravatar image for that email.

   ```
   <?php

   class GravatarHelper
   {

     /**
     * validate_gravatar
     *
     * Check if the email has any gravatar image or not
     *
     * @param  string $email Email of the User
     * @return boolean true, if there is an image. false otherwise
     */
     public static function validate_gravatar($email) {
       $hash = md5($email);
       $uri = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash . '?d=404';
       $headers = @get_headers($uri);
       if (!preg_match("|200|", $headers[0])) {
         $has_valid_avatar = FALSE;
       } else {
         $has_valid_avatar = TRUE;
       }
       return $has_valid_avatar;
     }

     /**
     * gravatar_image
     *
     *  Get the Gravatar Image From An Email address
     *
     * @param  string $email User Email
     * @param  integer $size  size of image
     * @param  string $d     type of image if not gravatar image
     * @return string        gravatar image URL
     */
     public static function gravatar_image($email, $size=0, $d="") {
       $hash = md5($email);
       $image_url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . $hash. '?s='.$size.'&d='.$d;
       return $image_url;
     }

   }
   ```

You can use then like:

```
if (GravatarHelper::validate_gravatar($email)) {
   echo GravatarHelper::gravatar_image($email, 200, "identicon");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get an email's avatar set on Gravatar.com or generate a default avatar if no avatar found for that email.

You just need to pass an email as a parameter and call this function anywhere in your project.

```
public function  get_avatar($email){

    $url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'; // The gravatar's API url
    $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ); // Hash the user's email
    $url .='.png?s=300'; // Get a custom image size

        //Extract the image if is set on Gravatar

    if ( isset($img) ) {
        foreach ( isset($atts) as $key => $val )
            $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
    }

    return $url; // Return the avatar's url or the default avatar if no image found.

}
```