# How can i set a gravatar in jetpack newsletter email?

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

i want to know only how jetpack set gravatar in newsletter email body.
I have done lots of googling but didn't find a best solution.
Actually i want following.
 1. When jetpack send newsletter and receiver has gravatar on http://en.gravatar.com/ then
    newsletter should receiver's gravatar **Currently** It is showing sender's gravatar. 
   2.In other case , when jetpack send newsletter and receiver has not 
 
    gravatar on http://en.gravatar.com/ then custom image will show.

Thank you for help in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build a url of a GRAVATAR image from a given email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718860/how-to-build-a-url-of-a-gravatar-image-from-a-given-email)

Comment: There is no "Newsletter" module in JetPack. If you're talking about "Subscriptions", I believe the email is composed at WordPress.com servers.